# Using Janet Basis to solve a nonlinear polynomial system

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, computer-algebra-systems

I am trying to solve a nonlinear polynomial equation system using Janet basis, when they have finite many solutions. For example the solution of the system:

$$xy^2-y^3-3x^2=0,x^2+y^2+xy=0.$$

There is a hint saying that after finding the Janet Basis of the ideal $$I=\langle xy^2-y^3-3x^2,x^2+y^2+xy\rangle$$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, one can find a basis for the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $T:=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/I$, and then a matrix of the linear map $f_{x}:T\rightarrow T$ defined as $v\rightarrow xv$ and the same for $y$, and then somehow using the minimal polynomials of the matrices of these maps.

Ok, I found the Janet Basis of $I$, and it is $$J=\{p_{1}=x^2+xy+y^2, p_{2}=xy^2-y^3+3xy+3y^2, p_{3}=y^4-3y^3+6xy+6y^2\}$$ with multiplicative set $\{x,y\}$ for $p_{1}$ and multiplicative set $\{y\}$ for $p_{2},p_{3}$, and the basis of the factor ring as $\mathbb{R}$-vector space is $B= \{ 1, y, x, y^2, yx, y^3\}$.

So we can now easily find the matrices of $f_{x},f_{y}$ and also their minimal polynomials, but what can we do more to determine the solutions of the equations system, and what does this have to do with eigenvalues and diagonalization of the matrices of $f_{x},f_{y}$.

Thanks for any help or hint.

Comment: Are you looking for real or complex solutions or something else?

Comment: I am looking to understand what is the relation between all these concepts, as answer to your question would like to say all solutions including complex solutions.

Comment: Take a look at [that](http://wwwb.math.rwth-aachen.de/Janet/janet.html).

Comment: To answer that part of the question that was left unanswered: "*what does this have to do with eigenvalues and diagonalization of the matrices of fx, fy.*" Although it does not deal with Janet bases but rather Groebner bases, I would suggest "Using Algebraic Geometry" by Cox, O'Shea and Little. They discuss a lot the use of eingenvalues of the matrices of these linear mappings (see chapter 2, paragraph 4, "solving equations via eigenvectors and eigenvalues"). Please could you tell me what is the reference you are using for Janet bases? I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: May be this website could help you http://wwwb.math.rwth-aachen.de/Janet/index.html , the course is called computer algebra, but written in German, and it is unfortunately  not available online.

Answer (score 0):

In this case all solutions can be found by elementary considerations. Multiplying the second equation by $y-2x$ and adding it to the first equation gives
$$
x^2(2x+y+3)=0.
$$
Then it follows immediately that $x=y=0$, or 
$$
(x,y)=\left( \frac{\sqrt{-3}-3}{2}, -\sqrt{-3}\right),\; \left( \frac{-\sqrt{-3}-3}{2}, \sqrt{-3}\right).
$$
Over the real numbers, only $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is possible.
If there is no elementary way to solve such a system, one needs to employ other techniques, such as Groebner bases, Janet bases and Janet-like Gröbner bases or similar tools.